# scio type safe BigQuery classes - annotation issue

Tags: scala, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, spotify-scio

I am trying to use type safe BigQuery classes. I have also installed [intellij scio plugin](https://github.com/spotify/scio/wiki/FAQ#how-to-make-intellij-idea-work-with-type-safe-bigquery-classes). But i get the error,

> Error:(37, 21) type arguments [RowElement] do not conform to method typedBigQuery's type parameter bounds [T <: com.spotify.scio.bigquery.types.BigQueryType.HasAnnotation]
>       sc.typedBigQueryRowElement

Here is my scala code:

```scala
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

  @BigQueryType.fromQuery("select id, org, env from TABLE") 
  class RowElement

  val (sc: ScioContext, arg) = ContextAndArgs(args)
  sc.typedBigQuery[RowElement]("select id, org, env from TABLE")
    .saveAsTypedBigQuery("TABLE_DEST")
  sc.close()
}
```

Comment: Did you resolve the case yet? I have a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

All `@BigQueryType` annotations should be in the top level of an `object` to avoid any macro expansion issues. For example:

`object MyPipeline {
  @BigQueryType.fromQuery("...") class MyRecord
}`